# Understanding AWK and CSV files

Tags: bash, csv, awk

How can I write an AWK program that analyses a list of fields in CSV files, count the number of each different string in the specified field, and print out the count of each string that is found? I have only coded in C and Java, so I am completely confused on the syntax of AWK. I understand the simplest of concepts, however, AWK is structured much differently. Any time is appreciated, thank you!

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ""
}
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) 
        freq[$i]++
    PROCINFO ["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc" #this got the desired result
}
END {
    for {this in freq) 
        printf "%s\t%d\n", this, freq[this]
}
```

On a CSV file containing:

```
Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
A, B, C, D
A, E, F, G
Z, E, C, D
Z, W, C, Q
```

I am able to obtain the result:

```
A     2
B     1
C     3
Q     1
D     1
E     2
F     1
,     12
G     1
W     1
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4     1
Z     2
```

This is the desired result:

```
A       10
C       7
D       2
E       2
Z       2
B       1
Q       1
Field1  1
Field2  1
F       1
Field3  1
G       1
Field4  1
W       1
```

There is an edit to my code which is commented.

Comment: SO isn't a tutoring service. You'll need to read a tutorial to learn the basics. But if you understand C and Java, it shouldn't be that hard to pick it up. `awk` mainly automates the loop of reading a line and splitting it into fields for you.

Comment: Thank you, as I am reading more now. I apologize, I am still pretty knew to SO and coding in general. From what I am seeing, AWK is pretty concise, but I am finding more about commands than I am on actual syntactical usage.

Comment: Please edit your question (Q) to show the required output based on your sample file. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed your code:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {                                     # you need BEGIN block for FS
    FS = ", *"                              # your data had ", " and "," seps
}                                           # ... based on your sample output
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        freq[$i]++
}
END {
    for(this in freq)                       # fixed a parenthesis
        printf "%s\t%d\n", this, freq[this]
}' file
```

Output (using GNU awk. Other awks displayed output in different order):

```
A       2
B       1
C       3
Q       1
D       2
Field1  1
E       2
Field2  1
F       1
Field3  1
G       1
Field4  1
W       1
Z       2
```

Comment: Thank you! Syntactically, can I write code similar to other languages to have this print in ascending or descending order?

Comment: `for(i in a)` will write out in implementation specific order (which might appear random). If you want the output in some specific order, you need to write (google) some sorting algorithm or use GNU awk (see for example: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html).

Comment: Meet this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64456277/difficulty-understanding-awk-syntax/64456461#64456461

Comment: But syntactically if you want to write a program that doesn't read and process file, use `BEGIN {}` block (or `END`), the looping and processing of file records happens in `{}` (ie. not `BEGIN/END`) and you can write functions.

Comment: One last question. How can I get the FIELDS_LIST from the command-line arguments using `argv`? Say, using the command `./awkprogram.awk 1,3 example.csv`?

Comment: What is `FIELDS_LIST`?

Comment: I apologize, it was late and I guess I did not realize I asked in such a manner. @James Brown, I was able to figure it out using the `split` method from the other post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AWK really isn't the right tool for this job. While AWK can interpret Comma or Tab separated data, it has no concept of field enclosures or escapes. So it could handle a simple example like:

```
Month,Day
January,Sunday
February,Monday
```

but would fail with this valid example:

```
Month,Day
January,"Sunday"
February,"Monday"
```

Because of that, I would recommend considering another language. Something like Python:

```py
import csv
o = open('a.csv')
for m in csv.DictReader(o):
   print(m)
```

https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Or Ruby:

```rb
require 'csv'
CSV.table('a.csv').each do |m|
   p m
end
```

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Or even PHP:

```php
<?php
$r = fopen('a.csv', 'r');
$a_head = fgetcsv($r);
while (true) {
   $a_row = fgetcsv($r);
   if (feof($r)) {
      break;
   }
   $m_row = array_combine($a_head, $a_row);
   print_r($m_row);
}
```

https://php.net/function.fgetcsv