# Difficulty understanding AWK syntax

Tags: bash, csv, awk

So I will admit I am completely new to AWK and have no idea how to use it, however I am trying to work off a code sample from the GNU awk user guide.

```
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        freq[$i]++
}

END {
    for (word in freq)
        printf "%s\t%d\n", word, freq[word]
}
```

This code snippet simply prints the count of every word present in the in freq

```
    {
    data[++data_index] = $0
    }

END {
    produce_numbers(data)
    for(i in freq)
        printf("%s\t%d", i, freq[i])
}

function produce_numbers(sortedarray)
{
    n = asort(sortedarray)
    sum = 0

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        freq[$i]++
    }

    return
}
```

This is one I am trying to use. I am sure it has several mistakes (Obviously because any output I have is wrong or nonexistant) but I am not experienced enough to know the syntax. Also the file I am trying to pass is something like this

```
A
B
A
C
B
A
C
D
```

Comment: What is that supposed to do, ie. what's the expected output? You might want to check this one out, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64456016/understanding-awk-and-csv-files/64456311#64456311

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reorganized and fixed that:

```
function produce_numbers(sortedarray)
{
    n = asort(sortedarray)
    # sum = 0                          # not used

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        freq[sortedarray[i]]++         # $i is unusable at this point
    }
    return
}
{
    data[++data_index] = $0
}
END {
    produce_numbers(data)
    for(i in freq)
        printf("%s\t%d\n", i, freq[i])  # added newline to output
}
```

Output:

```
A       3
B       2
C       2
D       1
```